# Keyboard layouts failing to apply

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have an Ubuntu 11.04 install for which I can't seem to get the correct (UK English) keyboard mapping set on. Running setxkmap produces an error:

"*XKB extension not present on :10.0*".

If go to *System -> Keyboards -> Layouts* and select the only layout installed "English Keymap" and press Show, I get a blank dialog.

I'm using xrdp and that this is almost certainly connected to xrdp using it's own keyboard mapping files. What I can't tell is how it can be changed.

Does anyone know how I can install and activate the correct keymap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your own keymap

- Log onto the console
- Run setxkbmap with the parameters that correspond to your layout
- `xrdp-genkeymap filename`

so in my case I did

- `setxkbmap –model pc104 –layout us –variant dvorak`
- `xrdp-genkeymap km-0409.ini`

The keymap I ended up with had problems with some keys (eg arrow keys) so I had to copy keys 98 to 107 from the original keymap file.

Comment: Daniel: Thanks! This was exactly the problem for me. I hope your advice is easy to find for anyone in the future!

Comment: Did anyone manage to specify xrdp's keyboard layout remotely? It seems `setxkbmap` needs to be run locally on the machine, because I only get XKB extension not present on :display.

Comment: I have the same problem as @HåvardGeithus. When I run the `setxkbmap`command, I get the message `XKB extension not present on `. How could one tackle that?

Comment: solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1148671/854571