# What may be the reason for incorrect keypresses interpreting in VNC session?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, remote-desktop, vnc, qt

I have Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS installed with VNC server (`tightvncserver`).

I connect to this VNC server from other machine (VNC client) with Remmina 1.1.2 (as in 16.04 LTS) using default settings.

Using VNC client I see that keyboard:

- works normally if I run GTK-based applications - all keypresses are interpreted normally in Pluma, Chromium, MATE Terminal;
- works normally in NCurses based application - all keypresses are interpreted normally in Nano and Midnight Commander editor;
- works with errors on Qt5-based applications such as Kate, Retext, Qt5 Assistant and so on - here keys with letters and numbers are messed, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are interpreted as numbers; <kbd>Enter</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Space</kbd>.

What may cause this strange behavior in Qt-apps? Which settings should I adjust? And on which side - on client or on server?

---

Some debug info - terminal output for `kate` and `setxkbmap` in VNC session:

> ```
> $ setxkbmap 
> XKB extension not present on :1
>
> $ kate
> Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
> ```

It may be a clue.

Comment: To give searching some keywords people are looking for here, when this happens typing "asdf" on a US keyboard as a sample gets mapped to "abfh".  It's particularly frustrating if you have any sort of login prompt  to fill in, because when typing a blanked out password you won't see the problem--and your Enter/Return key won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bug in Qt versions < 5.11:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44938
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814959
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1831505

So the list of affected Ubuntu versions includes two current LTS versions - 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.
The bug is fixed in 18.10 and 19.04, but they are not LTS, so we need stable usable solution for LTS versions:

- For 16.04 LTS version exists the following solution - setup `x11vnc` server and use it instead of `tightvncserver`.
  It is very fast, reliable and stable. And it should be noted that [Epoptes](http://www.epoptes.org/) uses it for monitoring and assisting of many LTSP clients in realtime.
- For 18.04 LTS one have to install `tigervnc-standalone-server` and set it up.